# How to detect "for internal use only" entities from Dynamics CRM metadata

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to read (FetchXml) the content of all the readable attributes of all the entities based on the list I get using the metadata webservice.

This works fine except for 3 entities ("resourcegroupexpansion", "workflowwaitsubscription" and "interprocesslock") for which I systematically get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Server was unable to process request.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <error>
          <code>0x80040216</code>
          <description>An unexpected error occurred.</description>
          <type>Platform</type>
        </error>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328086.aspx those 3 entities are for internal use only which might explain why I get an error (having said that I’m able to read other “internal use only” entities).

So my question is this: how can I detect from the metadata which entities are “for internal use only” and which are not ?
Of course, I could hard-code the list of entities based on the documentation but I don’t find it very satisfying.

Comment: I have the same question for CRM 2011. Did you ever find a way to determine 'internal use only' fields?

Comment: FYI: I posted a similar question on [the MS boards](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/09ce091b-fcee-4c25-8012-6e543124498c/?prof=required) and got a couple of response which may help some people.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is No flag to identify the "for Internal use only" entities.

But one thing I noticed from XrmToolbox Metadata browser - the description column of entity is having "for Internal use only" text for ~15 entities.

We can leverage the same by identifying & updating this field with unique values for internal system entities (thru some unsupported way like export solution, modify & reimport). Then description field text can be used to filter out these internal entities.

I never tried this. Will try & update my answer soon.